# Targeting multiple instances of the same class/ID with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm trying at the moment to target multiple instances of the same `div` class (`.overlay`) - the basic idea I'm trying to execute is that each div contains a HTML5 video inside another wrapped div which on `mouseenter` reveals itself, sets the video timeline to 0 and plays, and on `mouseout` resets the video to 0 again.

The problem I'm having is that only the first item of my grid works at the moment with nothing happening on the rollover of the others. This is my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.overlay').mouseenter(function(){
            $('#testvideo').get(0).play();
            }).mouseout(function() {
            $('#testvideo').get(0).pause();
            $('#testvideo').get(0).currentTime = 0;
            })
        });
```

I've also tried the following

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.overlay').mouseenter.each(function(){
            $('#testvideo').get(0).play();
            }).mouseout(function() {
            $('#testvideo').get(0).pause();
            $('#testvideo').get(0).currentTime = 0;
            })
        });
```

but that simply broke the functionality all together!

Here is a fiddle showing what should happen: http://jsfiddle.net/jameshenry/ejmfydfy/

The only difference between this and the actual site is that there are multiple grid items and thumbnails. I also don't want the behaviour to by asynchronous but rather individual - does anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong (I'm guessing my javascript!)

Comment: Your fiddle only shows one element. If your code doesn't work for 2+ elements, how will we test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using always `$('#testvideo')`, independent on the `div` you're entering the mouse. Since the HTML's `id` property must be unique, only the first element that you set the id `testvideo` will work the way you expect.

You should be using the `video` tag referenced by the `div.overlay`, or you could add a CSS class to the `video` tags, so you could use that class to find the video.

The code below will get the overlayed video, independent of which it is.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.overlay').hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('video').get(0).play();
  }, function() {
    var video = $(this).parent().find('video').get(0);
    video.pause();
    video.currentTime = 0;
  });
});
```

Take a look [at your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ejmfydfy/3/).

Comment: Amazing thank you. I thought it could be something to do with the ID tag, but didn't think to associate by the video tag.

Answer (score 0):

The first way you did it should work, the second one not. But, you shouldn't use an id like `#testvideo` if there are a lot of videos (one on each `.overley` element). Having multiple instances of the same id produce unexpected behaviuor, like *"only working on the first item"*.

You should change your `#testvideo` with `.testvideo` and change your code to something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.overlay').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).find('.testvideo').play();
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).find('.testvideo').pause();
        $(this).find('.testvideo').currentTime = 0;
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Alvaro - I gave this code a shot (including changing the video tag to include a class rather than ID) but unfortunately it didn't seem to work!